# Filtered Query in Access Form

Tags: ms-access, selection, subform

I have a form with a subform in it. There is a combo box in the header that is called cboBU that actively filters the subform query after each selection. My question is, when I load the form there is no data in the subform, this is because I have no selection in cboBU, how do I get the subform to show all results unless a cboBU selection occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create filter programmatically

Sample:

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()

SubFormCtlName.Form.Filter = "idCity=" & cboCity.Value & " AND " _
"idCountry=" & cboCountry.Value
SubFormCtlName.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```